# Using XPath within a single XElement to find only nodes that has a child node with specific Attribute

Tags: c#, linq, xpath

The error was related to invalid chars in the document. Thanks for the support guys.

I am trying to get all File elements that has a Property where attribute Name has a value of "Sensitivity" and only that files. I use the code below

```
XDocument doc = GetXDocument(manifestFileName, folder);

var listItems = doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "ListItem").ToList();
var files = doc.Descendants().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName == "File").ToList();

foreach(var file in files)
{
    var test = file.XPathSelectElement("/Properties/Property[@Name='Sensitivity']");
}
```

XML for each file:

```
<File Url="xx.docx" Id="f9d59fd3-b251-4f9a-8661-56f50b4e7a28" >
    <Properties>             
        <Property Name="vti_folderitemcount" Type="Integer" Access="ReadOnly" Value="0" />
        <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Type="String" Access="ReadWrite" Value="0x010100A3FB749C35EEAA489263F8BF9AA09896" />
        <Property Name="Sensitivity" Type="String" Access="ReadWrite" Value="General" />               
    </Properties>
</File>
```

Test is always NULL. Am I using the XElement wrong?

I also tried following

```
var test = File.XPathSelectElement("/File/Properties/Property[@Name='Sensitivity']");
```

[image]

I also tried directly on the XDocument:
[image]

Comment: I think you want `doc.XPathSelectElement("//File[Properties/Property[@Name='Sensitivity']]")`?

Comment: That will work o the complete document. I need to do it within a single XElement.

Comment: "I am trying to get all File elements that has a Property where attribute Name has a value of "Sensitivity" and only that files." That's exactly what `"//File[Properties/Property[@Name='Sensitivity']]"` selects, so I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking for then...

Comment: Your totally right. Your approach would be better. I just tried and it return 0 elements however. I changed XPathSelectElement to XPathSelectElements to get all the files. But still no results :(

Comment: I updated my original post with your input.

Comment: Problem was related to invalid chars in the Document. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var test = file.XPathSelectElement("/File/Properties/Property[@Name='Sensitivity']");
```

Result:

```
{<Property Name="Sensitivity" Type="String" Access="ReadWrite" Value="General" />}
```